# Two conditions for Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a piece of code that automatically removes all the dashes if the ID isn't null.  It was brought to my attention that these also need to always have 9 numbers.  However when you lead with zeros the 0's are automatically cut off.  How do I add another condition to the id.  Something like

if i.id.length < 9 add 0's to the front until it equals 9?

**Original code**

```
retval.Add(new SpreadsheetColumnSetup<Row>("ID", i =>
    (i.Id == null)
        ? i.Id
        : i.Id.Replace("-", "")));
```

Comment: ints.Add(new object("ID", i => (i.Id == null ? i.Id : i.Id.Replace("-", "") && i.Id.Length < 9 ? ..append zeros )));

Comment: "However when you lead with zeros the 0's are automatically cut off. "  Cut off by what?  Are you saying that you are setting it to a string that contains the leading zeroes, but they are being removed somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PadLeft` method as @itsme86 suggested. You can also simplify overall lambda with null conditional operator if you are using C# 6+

```
i => i.Id?.Replace("-", "").PadLeft(9, '0')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [string.PadLeft()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
i => (i.Id == null ? i.Id : i.Id.Replace("-", "").PadLeft(9, '0'))
```

Comment: You will iterate characters from string or get null reference exception here

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Nope, you still have `someNullString.Select(blah-blah)`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Okay, that one should do it. So picky ;)